# alignment of pgfplot's figures

Tags: pgfplots

I'm trying to put to put 2 graphs aligned, here is my MWE:

```
\documentclass[11pt, letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage[right=1.5cm,left=1.5cm,top=2.5cm,bottom=2.0cm,headsep=1.2cm,footskip=1.5cm]{geometry} % Márgenes





\begin{document}


\begin{figure}[!htbp]
\begin{tabular}{c c }
\begin{subfigure}{0.45\textwidth}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\pgfplotsset{
x coord trafo/.code={\pgfmathparse{#1^0.5}\pgfmathresult},
yticklabel style={/pgf/number format/fixed},
x coord inv trafo/.code={\pgfmathparse{#1^2}\pgfmathresult}}
\begin{axis}[
yticklabel style={/pgf/number format/fixed},
height=7.5cm,
width=7.5cm,
yticklabel style={/pgf/number format/fixed},
xlabel=$t $ (min),
ylabel= {s(t) = $L_{0}-L$ (mm)},
%grid=major,
y dir=reverse,
]
\addlegendentry[font=\tiny]{0,1 kg/cm$^{2}$}
\addplot[black, small,mark=*,mark size=1pt] coordinates {
(0.000001, 0.000)
(0.100, 0.032)
(0.250, 0.032)
(0.500, 0.032)
(1.000, 0.034)
(2.250, 0.034)
(4.000, 0.036)
(6.250, 0.036)
(9.000, 0.037)
(12.250, 0.039)
(16.000, 0.039)
(20.250, 0.040)
(25.000, 0.040)
(40.000, 0.041)
(60.000, 0.043)
(90.000, 0.043)
(120.000, 0.045)
(180.000, 0.048)
(480.000, 0.051)
(1440.000, 0.051)
};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{0.1 kg/cm$^{2}$}
\label{fig:01}
\end{subfigure}
 & 
\begin{subfigure}{0.45\textwidth}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\pgfplotsset{
x coord trafo/.code={\pgfmathparse{#1^0.5}\pgfmathresult},
x coord inv trafo/.code={\pgfmathparse{#1^2}\pgfmathresult}}
\begin{axis}[
height=7.5cm,
width=7.5cm,
xlabel=$t$ (min),
ylabel= {s(t) = $L_{0}-L$ (mm)},
%grid=major,
y dir=reverse,
]
\addlegendentry[font=\tiny]{0,25 kg/cm$^{2}$}
\addplot[red, small,mark=*,mark size=1pt] coordinates {
(0.000001, 0.000)
(0.100, 0.129)
(0.250, 0.159)
(0.500, 0.177)
(1.000, 0.189)
(2.250, 0.204)
(4.000, 0.209)
(6.250, 0.214)
(9.000, 0.219)
(12.250, 0.221)
(16.000, 0.224)
(20.250, 0.227)
(25.000, 0.229)
(40.000, 0.233)
(60.000, 0.238)
(90.000, 0.241)
(120.000, 0.245)
(180.000, 0.249)
(480.000, 0.259)
(1440.000, 0.261)
};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{0.2 kg/cm$^{2}$}
\label{fig:02}
\end{subfigure}
\\
\end{tabular}
\end{figure}




\end{document}
```

but the output is not aligned. I suspected this is because the left hand graph has the y axis format different (I tried to change it and failed), but then I realized that this is not the case either, because the top of the right hand graph is not aligned with the top of the $10^{-2}$.

Is there a way I can fix this? 
Do you know other method for aligning them other than tabular?

Comment: Unrelated to the alignment problem: Wouldn't a log scale for the x axis (`xmode=log` instead of the `x coord trafo`) make the graph clearer?

Comment: @Jake, for determining the coefficient of consolidation of a soil there are several methods, Taylor's method uses the square root of time for doing that, that's why I need to use that strange scale.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not using the optional argument for `subfigure`? In the following example I chose `b` (for alignment at the bottom):

```
\documentclass[11pt, letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage[right=1.5cm,left=1.5cm,top=2.5cm,bottom=2.0cm,headsep=1.2cm,footskip=1.5cm]{geometry} % Márgenes

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.45\textwidth}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\pgfplotsset{
x coord trafo/.code={\pgfmathparse{#1^0.5}\pgfmathresult},
yticklabel style={/pgf/number format/fixed},
x coord inv trafo/.code={\pgfmathparse{#1^2}\pgfmathresult}}
\begin{axis}[
yticklabel style={/pgf/number format/fixed},
height=7.5cm,
width=7.5cm,
yticklabel style={/pgf/number format/fixed},
xlabel=$t $ (min),
ylabel= {s(t) = $L_{0}-L$ (mm)},
%grid=major,
y dir=reverse,
]
\addlegendentry[font=\tiny]{0,1 kg/cm$^{2}$}
\addplot[black, small,mark=*,mark size=1pt] coordinates {
(0.000001, 0.000)
(0.100, 0.032)
(0.250, 0.032)
(0.500, 0.032)
(1.000, 0.034)
(2.250, 0.034)
(4.000, 0.036)
(6.250, 0.036)
(9.000, 0.037)
(12.250, 0.039)
(16.000, 0.039)
(20.250, 0.040)
(25.000, 0.040)
(40.000, 0.041)
(60.000, 0.043)
(90.000, 0.043)
(120.000, 0.045)
(180.000, 0.048)
(480.000, 0.051)
(1440.000, 0.051)
};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{0.1 kg/cm$^{2}$}
\label{fig:01}
\end{subfigure}\hfill
\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.45\textwidth}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\pgfplotsset{
x coord trafo/.code={\pgfmathparse{#1^0.5}\pgfmathresult},
x coord inv trafo/.code={\pgfmathparse{#1^2}\pgfmathresult}}
\begin{axis}[
height=7.5cm,
width=7.5cm,
xlabel=$t$ (min),
ylabel= {s(t) = $L_{0}-L$ (mm)},
%grid=major,
y dir=reverse,
]
\addlegendentry[font=\tiny]{0,25 kg/cm$^{2}$}
\addplot[red, small,mark=*,mark size=1pt] coordinates {
(0.000001, 0.000)
(0.100, 0.129)
(0.250, 0.159)
(0.500, 0.177)
(1.000, 0.189)
(2.250, 0.204)
(4.000, 0.209)
(6.250, 0.214)
(9.000, 0.219)
(12.250, 0.221)
(16.000, 0.224)
(20.250, 0.227)
(25.000, 0.229)
(40.000, 0.233)
(60.000, 0.238)
(90.000, 0.241)
(120.000, 0.245)
(180.000, 0.249)
(480.000, 0.259)
(1440.000, 0.261)
};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{0.2 kg/cm$^{2}$}
\label{fig:02}
\end{subfigure}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I should have thought that. Gracias!

Comment: @Francisco ¡De nada!

Answer (score 1):

In this solution, the first thing I did to make it easier to see the solution was to put your two images in separate files and then `\input` them to the figure.  In this case, I use a `\shortstack` so that the figures stack from the baseline.

```
\documentclass[11pt, letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage[right=1.5cm,left=1.5cm,top=2.5cm,bottom=2.0cm,headsep=1.2cm,footskip=1.5cm]{geometry} % Márgenes

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[!htbp]
\small
\shortstack{\input{pica}\\(a) 0.1 kg/cm$^{2}$}
~~~~~
\shortstack{\input{picb}\\(b) 0.2 kg/cm$^{2}$}
\normalsize
\caption{This is my figure}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]